# Can a local webapp run on iOS?

Tags: html, ios, web-applications, local, offline

I searched on the Internet for my question, but I cannot seem to find a solid answer. So I am hoping this community can give me a more detailed look into this. Since I do not own an iOS device myself I cannot test this out at the moment.

**The context:**

I want to make a webapp with a certain functionality in it. This webapp cannot and may not be published in the Appstore (or Play Store for that matter). The webapp is for a business to use.

The reason for the webapp is that the same code can be used for both iOS, Android and Windows Phone. Since performance is not key (it would be a fairly simple and straightforward app) I like this approach since it saves time.

**The approach:**

I can make a webapp in a single file if needed. I can include all javascript and css in the code, in stead of linking to external files and thus create the 1 file. This would result in a single HTML file containing the entire webapp (this would be preferred I guess :).

In this case I would like to place this webapp locally on the device (again, iOS, Android and Windows Phone). Obviously by tapping on the file it would start the webapp on the browser on the device. The app is not used often, but it in key situations it needs to be accessible and use-able offline.

**The question:**

I know it is possible to this on an Android phone, I am almost sure it can be done on a Windows Phone, but I have doubts concerning iOS. Is this a possible scenario? Or would I need to find other solutions (like a webserver to place the webapp on with a manifest file to make offline use possible, although this would implicate more obstacles to develop and distribute the app)?

Thanks in advance for taking your time to answer my question.

Comment: As you mention, to have an offline webapp, you would need to create a Manifest, since you can't save web pages to local "disk" on iOS. What obstacles are you thinking of?

Comment: The obstacle would be more of policy then technical. I cannot place the app on an external webserver, but only on a internal one. But mobile devices can only connect to quest network and therefore cannot connect to the webserver (as it is designed at the moment, by policy).

Comment: Yeah, that is tricky. But wouldn't the same problem then also exist for the native wrapper solutions, as you need a server from which you can install the `.ipa`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I use for this is Cordova to "wrap my app": 
http://cordova.apache.org/

It "wraps" your web app into an distributable app.
That is the only way I could make it work **offline** on most mobile devices.

Distribution to the phones is done via an Inhouse Appstore.
An Inhouse Appstore is not very complicated. 
It is basicly a simple html file which points via a simple href to your "wrapped" apps. (*.ipa for Apple, *.apk for Adnroid).

If you make a simple authentication mechanism on your store you prevent "3th parties" from using your app.

For Android it works "out of the box" to be able to install apps NOT using PlayStore.

For Apple there is a little trick called "Enterprise Distribution". This is needed to sign your apps to be able to allow them being installed over the air on non-jailbroken devices.
It is not free: https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/

For Windows Phone things work about the same as Apple:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj206943(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: Thanks for sharing your thoughts about this. I know Cordova very well, and I will scout that for this case. Also will check your suggestions about inhouse Appstore.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can load your web application into IOS device. I have recently done a task where I need to run HTML( lots of htm, JS and CSS files) in a native iOS application.

For that, I have loaded( followed some specific steps to load ) html file in UIWebView Control. so now, my native app behaving as like a web application.

If you are expecting the same above, so that I can explain you how to load that html files into a WebView control for you native iOS app.  Please let me know.